# Insert padding whitespace into string

Tags: java, string

Pretty basic problem, but difficult to get into an acceptable form:

I want to transform a string by inserting a padding every 3 whitespaces like

"123456789" -> "123 456 789"

"abcdefgh" -> "abc def gh"

My code currently is

```
public String toSpaceSeparatedString(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() < 3) {
    return s;
  }

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  int i; 
  for (i = 0; i < s.length()-3; i += 3) {
    builder.append(s.substring(i, i+3));
    builder.append(" ");
  }

  builder.append(s.substring(i, s.length()));

  return builder.toString();
}
```

Can anyone provide a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using a regular expression:

```
"abcdefgh".replaceAll(".{3}", "$0 ")
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar solution, but regex for such a simple task is always the _last_ resort. ;)

Comment: Really? I think regex is always the FIRST resort!

Comment: It can be done via an even easier regex.  Updated the answer.

Comment: @jellybean: it is a one-liner. if you add a good comment about what it is doing or put it into an utility method with a meaningful name, I think it's perfectly fine to use regex here.

Comment: After the update it's much more readable/acceptable, thank you.

Comment: @Bohemian: Not for me, I guess. ;) @tulskiy: I'm pretty suspicious about comments that make claims about how code behaves ... the code should be at least in some degree be comprehensible. But that topic has probably argued about a lot already ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `printf` or `String.format` like so:

```
 builder.append(String.format("%4s", threeDigitString));
```

More information on formatted output/strings [in the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: This is meant as a replacement for the code inside the `for` loop, as well as the append afterwards, right? Not bad, but I'd like to get rid of the ugly form of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't put a space if there's already one there:

```
"abcdef gh".replaceAll("\\s*(..[^ ])\\s*", "$1 "); // --> "abc def gh"
```

Comment: Thanks ... but not an option for me!

Comment: Cool - just trying to "over achieve" :)

Answer (score 1):

The `replaceAll` looks to be the best, but if you consider a number like 12345 it would be converted to 123 45. But in numbers I believe it should be 12 345

Comment: What alternative solution can you propose?