# How to insert characters into a Dart String?

Tags: flutter, dart, libraries

I would like to add some white spaces to a Dart String in a given position, exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438319/insert-padding-whitespace-into-string) (In Java).

so...

```
'XPTOXXSFXBAC' become 'XPTO XXSF XBAC'
```

Is there an easy way?

Comment: yes, see `String.replaceAllMapped()` method

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the [replaceAllMapped](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html) method from `String`, you have to add the regular expression, like this:

```
 final value =  "XPTOXXSFXBAC".replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r".{4}"), (match) => "${match.group(0)} ");
 print("value: $value");
```

Comment: a little more verbose than I expected, but thanks :)

Comment: But there is one issue if we separate using "-" then it will add - at the end of the string

Comment: This will add an extra space at the end of the string. To prevent that, use `trimRight()` method. `"XPTOXXSFXBAC".replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r".{4}"), (match) => "${match.group(0)} ").trimRight()`. If you are using a character different than space, use `str.substring(0, str.length - 1)`

Answer (score 22):

```
 var x= 'XPTOXXSFXBAC';
 x = x.substring(0, 4) + " " + x.substring(4, 8) + " " + x.substring(8, x.length);
 print(x) ;
```

Comment: This is only useful if you know the String will always be 12 long. What if you have a String longer or shorter? Will it become ABC DEF GHIJKLMNOPQRST?

Answer (score 18):

There is a dart package that provides some helper classes for String operations.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils
Install it with:

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.5.0
```

Usage

```dart
String s = "";
s = StringUtils.addCharAtPosition("1234567890", "-", 3);
print(s); // "123-4567890"
s = StringUtils.addCharAtPosition("1234567890", "-", 3, repeat: true); 
print(s); // "123-456-789-0"
s = StringUtils.addCharAtPosition("1234567890", "-", 12);
print(s); // "1234567890"
```

Additional information :

These are all methods from the StringUtils class.

```dart
String defaultString(String str, {String defaultStr = ''});
bool isNullOrEmpty(String s);
bool isNotNullOrEmpty(String s);
String camelCaseToUpperUnderscore(String s);
String camelCaseToLowerUnderscore(String s);
bool isLowerCase(String s);
bool isUpperCase(String s);
bool isAscii(String s);
String capitalize(String s);
String reverse(String s);
int countChars(String s, String char, {bool caseSensitive = true});
bool isDigit(String s);
bool equalsIgnoreCase(String a, String b);
bool inList(String s, List<String> list, {bool ignoreCase = false});
bool isPalindrome(String s);
String hidePartial(String s, {int begin = 0, int end, String replace = "*"});
String addCharAtPosition(String s, String char, int position,{bool repeat = false});
```

Comment: nice. i'll give a try

Comment: Good answer friend. This a lovely library. However, I preferred the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is unnecessarily specific: you just want to insert characters (or a String) into another Dart String.  Whitespace isn't special.

### Approach #1

```dart
String toSpaceSeparatedString(String s) {
  var start = 0;
  final strings = <String>[];
  while (start < s.length) {
    final end = start + 4;
    strings.add(s.substring(start, end));
    start = end;
  }
  return s.join(' ');
}
```

### Approach #2 (less efficient)

```dart
String toSpaceSeparatedString(String s) {
  const n = 4;
  assert(s.length % n == 0);
  var i = s.length - n;
  while (i > 0) {
    s = s.replaceRange(i, i, ' ');
    i -= n;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Approach #2 is less efficient (it needs to repeatedly insert into a `String` and therefore involves copying the same parts of the `String` repeatedly) and is more awkward (it iterates from the end of the `String` to the beginning so that indices are stable), and has more corner cases (for simplicity I'm assuming that the input string is evenly divisible by the substring length).  However, I'm including it here because it demonstrates using [`String.replaceRange`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/replaceRange.html), which can be generally useful to insert one `String` into another, and which probably would be simpler for one-off cases.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simpler version of @diegoveloper's answer by using [allMatches](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Pattern/allMatches.html). It won't be an extra separator by using `join`.

```
final myText = 'XPTOXXSFXBAC';
final separator = ' ';

final result = RegExp(r".{4}")
               .allMatches(myText)
               .map((e) => e.group(0))
               .join(separator);
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Showing Card Number Like 15XX XXXX XXXX 9876 in dart**

```dart
String num1 = "1567456789099876".replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<=.{2})\d(?=.{4})'), 'X');
String num  = num1.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r".{4}"), (match) => "${match.group(0)} ");

print(num); //15XX XXXX XXXX 9876
```